# Download A File And Insert Values Into A Database

Tags: php

```
<?php
// force to download a file
if(isset($_POST['download'])){
    $file = "images/dansyo_logo.png";
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
    header( "Content-Description: File Transfer");
    @readfile($file);
    if(@readfile($file)){
        echo'proceed';
    }else{
        echo'failded';
    }
}
?>

<form method='post'>
    <button name='download'>download</button>
</form>
```

I have the above code where i want the code to be able to download a file and in the same time insert values into my database.The code is functioning well that is i'm able to download a file.However,nothing is echoed after the file has downloaded or is downloading.

Comment: do whatever you want before header send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not going to echo since header will send the file to browser for download, if you wanted to do any kind of `db` submission just do it before header sent

```
$file = "images/dansyo_logo.png";

//Do your DB update here, before the header
if(is_readable($file)) {
  // insert into database 
} else {
    exit(basename($file)." not found.");
}

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
@readfile($file);
exit();
```

Note: `file_exists()` will return true on a directory.

Comment: hi Sanqueib,i have tried your concept but it is giving me this error,call to undefined function

Comment: try updated code, it should work, its working on my pc

Comment: Thanks for concern,and another question,i am trying to echo a value if the file is readable or not but is not giving me any result.What would be problem with the code

Comment: if file is readable it will start downloading, if not you can just use `exit( basename($file) . ' not found.' );` updated the answer